# Wifi on 16.04 takes a long time to find known and unknown local networks

Tags: networking, wireless, intel-wireless

I have been having an issue that's been bugging me and causing a few disruptions in my workflow on 16.04 on my ASUS x550la.

When clicking the wifi icon in the toolbar, no networks are displayed for quite a while. Sometimes I may go up to 5 minutes and still no network connection. Also trying to add a hidden network does not help. It still will not connect immediately. I find that this most frequently and severely happens when logging on from standby, although I have still experienced the issue even when I have been using the computer for quite some time. I would also like to note that 16.04 is not the only version that has given me this issue. I had the same problem on a different Lenovo laptop running 14 or so.

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

returns the following when connected:

```
description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless 7260
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 73
   serial: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=104.39.109.23 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:46 memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
```

Also, running

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

seemed to allow me to connect almost immediately after I ran the command, so It may be just an issue where my wireless card is not actively scanning  for networks. But I have not been able to recreate the issue to try this method again as of yet.

In any case, I would like to know what I can do to give me some better control over how quickly I can connect to a known network. Even if iwlist scan is my best option.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I suggest that you upgrade the firmware; from the terminal:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Then set your regulatory domain explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and let us know if connectivity is improved.

Comment: Ran commands and rebooted. Wifi connection was immediate upon boot. Hopefully, the effects will last. If not, I will return. Thank you!

Comment: This also worked for me, you just saved me hours of waiting for my WiFi to connect, now it connects instantly!
But doesn't linux firmware upgrade with normal software (system) updates? I regularly apply all the updates, why is it necessary to upgrade firmware manually like this?

Comment: @kovinet It isn't necessary unless you installed an older Ubuntu version (including an older linux-firmware package) on a computer with *newer* hardware for which the firmware will often only be found in the very latest linux-firmware package.

Comment: So in my case I have motherboard from 2012 and Ubuntu 16.04 which is from 2016 updating firmware was probably not a necessary part? I suppose `iw reg set` did the trick then...

Comment: @kovinet It's hard to say. Frankly, I generally just roll *all* of the probable fixes into one post and, most often, it works.

Comment: Is that a general method for upgrading any firmware in the machine? Or is it only applicable to some specific version(s) of Ubuntu? Or some specific hardware? (I.e. only the wifi? Or will it upgrade other stuff in my machine too?)

Comment: @zrajm It will upgrade *all* the firmware; although, please be aware that linux-firmware_1.161_all has been superceded many times since I wrote this answer in 2016. If you have a specific problem, please start your own new question and we'll be very glad to help.

Comment: This work perfectly on Ubuntu 19.04 with an Asus Zenbook, wifi network was detected right from the login screen. Although, to be honest, I did not update my firmware, just added my country code to /etc/default/crda.

Comment: Wow, thanks, setting regulatory domain explicitly fixed the issue for me.